# Fullcalendar month time format like weeks

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Can anyone suggests how could I change month time format to look like week format?

There is this calendar 'framework' http://fullcalendar.io/views/month/
If you changed to weeks, you could see it uses time like this:

`start_time - end_time`

In months calendar view, it only shows `start_time`.

I didn't find where I should change in view to show it exactly like in a week.

In default options I found this object:

```
        timeFormat : {
           // for agendaWeek and agendaDay               
           agenda: shortTimeformat + '{ - ' + shortTimeformat + '}', // 5:00 - 6:30
            // for all other views
            '': shortTimeformat.replace(/:mm/,'(:mm)')  // 7pm
        },
```

I tried duplicating agenda format for other views (simply replacing // 7pm format with the one above), but it didn't change anything.

Maybe someone have more experience with this Fullcalendar and can suggest something?

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`displayEventEnd` option](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventEnd/). It can be set globally or as [view-specific](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/).

```
//Globally
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    displayEventEnd: 'true',
    ...
}

//View specific
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    views: {
        month: {
            displayEventEnd: 'true',
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Note that the event must actually **have an end date** or it won't be shown. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/r0yp14gk/2/) with 3 different event types: `{start,end},{start},{allday}`